# How can we add database table column dynamically based on other table values in Sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_BuildTable 
          @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
          ,@Column1Name NVARCHAR(32)
          ,@Column1DataType NVARCHAR(32)
          ,@Column1Nullable NVARCHAR(32)
   AS

   DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE '+@TableName + '( '+@Column1Name+' '
   +@Column1DataType +' '+@Column1Nullable +') ON PRIMARY '

   EXEC (@SQLString)

   GO
```

I want to create a New table,The table column names are need to be add dynamically based on other database column values

Comment: Add the code you have tried so far. We need something to work on

Comment: i want to enter marks for students and saved into Databse,The subjects names are dynamic. it will change Based on class, this is the case

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make it in SQL?? If yes then you can use :

```
select * into newtable from oldtable
```

This will create a new table(duplicate) using old table names and data.

If you want all columns of a table you can use

```
sp_help tableName
```

as your sql query that will return you all details.

AND
If you want to do this with c# code you can get the column name as above

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, ConnectionString);    
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
string columnName =  table.Columns[desiredColumnIndex].ColumnName;
```

it will return column name which you can use in other sqlquery to create a new table. in your case if your resultant returns a single column you will pass 0 as index.

Comment: i don't want all columns from old table. I Just want one column values

Comment: Use **select [ColumnName] into newtable from OldTable**

Comment: i dont want to insert it, I want these [Column] values as column headers of new table